# activate C# function from html table

Tags: c#, html, html-table

How can i activate a C# function from a simple html table?

i'm working with ASP .Net

Appreciate,

Comment: How do you mean exactly? Something other than a link or button that does a post-back?

Comment: it could be done i think via onclick to call a java script which activate a function in my .cs file

Comment: Because C# code runs server-side, you need a way to invoke code running on the server and the way is either through an ASP.NET control that posts back to the server (naivists' answer) or through AJAX (Orbman's answer)

Answer (score 2):

Add a `<asp:Button id="id" text="label" OnClick="sub" runat="server" />` (or even `<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="sub" text="YourLinkText" />`, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) ) to your page, then define a function `sub()` to handle your call.
  The `sub()` function can be both in ASPX code or in code-behind file (it is advisable to choose the code-behind way)

See an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This would normally be done via [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)), if I understand you correctly.

**Edit:**

You could also use Windows Forms, but I work in an ASP.NET MVC world now, and hope to never use Windows Forms again.